# sleep and flush in php loop

Tags: php, loops, sleep

I have the following code:

```
<?php
$initialSleep = ( isset($_GET['is']) ) ? $_GET['is'] : 0; // seconds - default 0 if not specified
$loopCount = ( isset($_GET['lc']) ) ? $_GET['lc'] : 1; // default 1 if not specified
$loopSleep = ( isset($_GET['ls']) ) ? $_GET['ls'] : 1; // seconds - default 0 if not specified

sleep($initialSleep);

for ( $i = 0; $i < $loopCount; $i++) {
    sleep($loopSleep);
    echo time();
    ob_flush();
}
?>
```

My problem is the instead of getting the time() echoed out at intervals I get a total delay equal to loopCount * loopSleep  and then everything echoes out at once. I have seen other posts about this sort of thing and using flush() seems to fix it for most people - not me though.

Any help appreciated

Comment: `flush()` and `ob_flush()` are different things.

Comment: Hi - have tried flush and ob_flush to no effect - browser is firefox 6

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
ob_start();
for ( $i = 0; $i < $loopCount; $i++) {
    sleep($loopSleep);
    echo time();
    ob_flush();
    flush();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer - unfortunately still no good - when i give it parameters as follows: http://localhost/?is=0&lc=2&ls=3 - I get a 6 second delay and then 2 times written out at once.

Answer (score 0):

Your webserver may buffer on it's own if it thinks it will get a more efficiënt transfer that way. Maybe you can turn this off but it's probably not the most efficient in production.